# AttributeError: module 'deathbycaptcha' has no attribute 'SocketClient'

Tags: python-3.x, api

- import deathbycaptcha as dbc

  client = dbc.SocketClient(username, password)

  DBC version - 0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall that library and reinstall it with
pip install git+https://github.com/codevance/python-deathbycaptcha.git
it works for me